# Finding $x$, where $\int_{r-x}^r \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} dt = A$

Tags: definite-integrals, transcendental-equations

When solving my practical problem, I would need to compute $x$, given $A$ and $r$, where $x$ appears in the integral:

$$\int_{r-x}^r \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \text{d}t = A$$

It's quite a few years from my last calculus lesson, so I'm asking here.

thanks

Comment: Did you mean $\int_{r-x}^{r} \sqrt{r^2-t^2} \text{d}t$ (note the $t$). Using $x$ that way is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, it's circle with center (0,0). I used the equation of circle. I know the part of the area (Part) and I'd like to compute x, so that when I will cut the circle I have exactly the Part

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question to make it clearer. Are you looking for an exact formula? Or just some method to compute an approximate solution?

Comment: @Aryabhata My mistake, under the square root is x, not t. I think it shouldn't be nothing complex. Whole integral expresses a (part (segment) of a circle)/2. I know this part (how much percent I want to cut) and I need to compute the distance x.

Comment: @Aryabhata [The segment](http://www.mathopenref.com/segment.html) is the area (percentage) I know. I know the radius and I want to compute the distance x = distance between C and center of A-B.

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion. Since the current question (with $t$ not $x$) already has answers, I suggest you post a new question (tagged geometry), with clearer details (about the segment/chords etc which you described in the comments here) which will make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this has been presented as a calculus problem, it’s really a problem in high-school geometry. The integral represents the area of half a circular segment $S$. This segment is the area of the circle of radius $r$ that’s to the right of the vertical line $t=x$, in the $ty$-plane.

If the chord (here going between the points $\left(x,\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,\right)\,$) subtends an angle of $\alpha$, then the sector (pie-wedge) of angle $\alpha$ has area $\alpha r^2/2$. From this we subtract the area of the triangle whose vertices are the origin and the two points I mentioned previously. The altitude is $x$ and the (vertical) base is $2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ in length, so the area of the whole triangle has area $x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. We have to subtract this quantity from $\alpha r^2/2$ and get rid of the $\alpha$, which is $\arccos(x/r)$. That gives you the area of the whole sector, and our desired quantity is half that, you’re done.

Oh, yes, and if you wanted the “indefinite integral” of the function $\sqrt{r^2-t^2}$, this method is how you find it, though the method of “trigonometric substitution” would also do the same, with more work.

Comment: Thank you for smart solution. I only don't see why alpha * r^2 / 2 = area of that triangle. Is it some law? And seems that alpha/2 (not alpha) = arccos(x/r)

Comment: Now I [understand](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle-sector-segment.html)

Answer (score 1):

The result is a transcendental equation; I know of no closed-form solution:

$$\frac{2 A}{r^2} =  y \sqrt{1-y^2} + \arccos{y}$$

where

$$y = 1-\frac{x}{r}$$